# R fitting Frechet distribution: replicating the answer

Tags: r, distribution, data-fitting

I am doing a similar work to estimate the parameters of Frechet distribution given the guides provided here. The resource provided here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011584/7308826) which was very useful. But, after doing the steps I got the following error, "could not find function "checkparam". Any idea what is going wrong in the code? I am adding the modifeid code below:

#

## Copyright (c) 2010 Marie Laure Delignette-Muller, Christophe Dutang

```
    foo_mmedist <- function (data, distr, order, memp, start=NULL, fix.arg=NULL,
                     optim.method="default", lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, custom.optim=NULL, 
                     weights=NULL, silent=TRUE, gradient=NULL, ...) 
{
  if (!is.character(distr)) 
    stop("distr must be a character string naming a distribution")
  else 
    distname <- distr

  if (is.element(distname, c("norm", "lnorm", "pois", "exp", "gamma", "nbinom", "geom",
                             "beta", "unif", "logis")))
    meth <- "closed formula"
  else
    meth <- optim.method

  mdistname <- paste("m", distname, sep="")
  ddistname <- paste("d", distname, sep="")
  if(is.null(custom.optim))
    optim.method <- match.arg(optim.method, c("default", "Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN", "Brent"))

  if(!is.null(weights))
  {
    if(any(weights < 0))
      stop("weights should be a vector of integers greater than 0")
    if(!is.allint.w(weights))
      stop("weights should be a vector of (strictly) positive integers")
    if(length(weights) != NROW(data))
      stop("weights should be a vector with a length equal to the observation number")
    warning("weights are not taken into account in the default initial values")
  }

  if(meth != "closed formula")
  {

    if (!exists(as.character(expression(memp)), mode = "function"))
      stop(paste0("The moment ", mdistname, " function must be defined."))     
    # mdistname contains the good name of the theoretical moment function    
  }
  if (!(is.numeric(data) & length(data)>1)) 
    stop("data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1")

  if(meth == "closed formula")
  {
    n <- length(data)
    if(is.null(weights))
    {
      m <- mean(data)
      v <- (n - 1)/n*var(data)
    }else #weighted version from util-wtdstat.R
    {
      m <- wtd.mean(data, weights=weights)
      v <- wtd.var(data, weights=weights)
    }

    if (!is.null(fix.arg))
      stop("argument fix.arg cannot be used when a closed formula is used.")
    # Fitting by matching moments
    if (!(is.vector(data) & is.numeric(data) & length(data)>1))
      stop("data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1")
    if (distname == "norm") {
      estimate <- c(mean=m, sd=sqrt(v))
      order <- 1:2
    }
    if (distname == "lnorm") {
      if (any(data <= 0)) 
        stop("values must be positive to fit a lognormal distribution")
      sd2 <- log(1+v/m^2)
      estimate <- c(meanlog=log(m) - sd2/2, sdlog=sqrt(sd2))
      order <- 1:2            
    }



    if (distname == "pois") {
      estimate <- c(lambda=m)
      order <- 1          
    }
    if (distname == "exp") {
      estimate <- c(rate=1/m)
      order <- 1          
    }
    if (distname == "gamma" ) {
      shape <- m^2/v
      rate <- m/v
      estimate<-c(shape=shape, rate=rate)
      order <- 1:2            
    }
    if (distname == "nbinom" ) {
      size <- if (v > m) m^2/(v - m)
      else NaN
      estimate<-c(size=size, mu=m)
      order <- 1:2           
    }
    if (distname == "geom" ) {
      prob<-if (m>0) 1/(1+m)
      else NaN
      estimate<-c(prob=prob)
      order <- 1         
    }
    if (distname == "beta" ) {
      if (any(data < 0) | any(data > 1)) 
        stop("values must be in [0-1] to fit a beta distribution")
      aux<-m*(1-m)/v - 1
      shape1 <- m*aux
      shape2 <- (1-m)*aux
      estimate<-c(shape1=shape1, shape2=shape2)
      order <- 1:2            
    }
    if (distname == "unif" ) {
      min1 <- m-sqrt(3*v)
      max1 <- m+sqrt(3*v)
      estimate<-c(min1,max1)
      order <- 1:2            
    }
    if (distname == "logis" ) {
      scale <- sqrt(3*v)/pi
      estimate<-c(location=m, scale=scale)
      order <- 1:2            
    }
    res <- list(estimate=estimate, convergence=0, value=NULL, hessian=NULL,
                optim.function=NULL, order=order, memp=NULL, counts=NULL,
                optim.message=NULL)
    opt.meth <- fix.arg.fun <- NULL

  }else #an optimimisation has to be done, where fix.arg and start can be a function
  {
    start.arg <- start #to avoid confusion with the start() function of stats pkg (check is done lines 87-100)
    if(is.vector(start.arg)) #backward compatibility
      start.arg <- as.list(start.arg)

    # definition of starting/fixed values values
    argmdistname <- names(formals(mdistname))

    chfixstt <- checkparam (start.arg=start.arg, fix.arg=fix.arg, argdistname=argmdistname, errtxt=NULL, data10=head(data, 10), distname=distname)

    if(!chfixstt$ok)
      stop(chfixstt$txt)
    #unlist starting values as needed in optim()
    if(is.function(chfixstt$start.arg))
      vstart <- unlist(chfixstt$start.arg(data))
    else
      vstart <- unlist(chfixstt$start.arg)
    if(is.function(fix.arg)) #function
    { 
      fix.arg.fun <- fix.arg
      fix.arg <- fix.arg(data)
    }else
      fix.arg.fun <- NULL
    #otherwise fix.arg is a named list or NULL

    # end of the definition of starting/fixed values

    if(length(vstart) != length(order))
      stop("wrong dimension for the moment order to match")
    if(missing(memp)) 
      stop("the empirical moment function must be defined")
    #backward compatibility when memp is the name of the function and not the function itself
    if(is.character(memp))
      memp <- get0(memp, envir=pos.to.env(1))


    #check the memp function
    if(!is.function(memp)) 
      stop("the empirical moment must be defined as a function")
    if(is.null(weights))
    {
      txt <- "the empirical moment function must be a two-argument function of 'x', 'order'"
      if(length(formals(memp)) != 2)
        stop(txt)
      if(any(names(formals(memp)) != c("x", "order")))
        stop(txt)
    }else
    {
      txt <- "the empirical moment function must be a three-argument function of 'x', 'order', 'weights'"
      if(length(formals(memp)) != 3)
        stop(txt)
      if(any(names(formals(memp)) != c("x", "order", "weights")))
        stop(txt)
    }


    ############# MME fit using optim or custom.optim ##########

    # definition of the function to minimize : least square (Cramer - von Mises type)
    if(is.null(weights))
    {
      DIFF2 <- function(par, fix.arg, order, obs, mdistnam, memp, weights)
      {
        momtheo <- do.call(mdistnam, c(as.list(order), as.list(par), as.list(fix.arg)) )
        momemp <- as.numeric(memp(obs, order))
        (momemp - momtheo)^2
      }
      fnobj <- function(par, fix.arg, obs, mdistnam, memp, weights)
        sum( sapply(order, function(o) DIFF2(par, fix.arg, o, obs, mdistnam, memp)) )
    }else
    {
      DIFF2 <- function(par, fix.arg, order, obs, mdistnam, memp, weights)
      {
        momtheo <- do.call(mdistnam, c(as.list(order), as.list(par), as.list(fix.arg)) )
        momemp <- as.numeric(memp(obs, order, weights))
        (momemp - momtheo)^2
      }
      fnobj <- function(par, fix.arg, obs, mdistnam, memp, weights)
        sum( sapply(order, function(o) DIFF2(par, fix.arg, o, obs, mdistnam, memp, weights)) )
    }

    cens <- FALSE
    if(cens)
      stop("Moment matching estimation for censored data is not yet available.")


    owarn <- getOption("warn")
    # Try to minimize the stat distance using the base R optim function
    if(is.null(custom.optim))
    {
      hasbound <- any(is.finite(lower) | is.finite(upper))

      # Choice of the optimization method  
      if (optim.method == "default")
      {
        opt.meth <- ifelse(length(vstart) > 1, "Nelder-Mead", "BFGS") 
      }else
        opt.meth <- optim.method

      if(opt.meth == "BFGS" && hasbound && is.null(gradient))
      {
        opt.meth <- "L-BFGS-B"
        txt1 <- "The BFGS method cannot be used with bounds without provided the gradient."
        txt2 <- "The method is changed to L-BFGS-B."
        warning(paste(txt1, txt2))
      }

      options(warn=ifelse(silent, -1, 0))
      #select optim or constrOptim
      if(hasbound) #finite bounds are provided
      {
        if(!is.null(gradient))
        {
          opt.fun <- "constrOptim"
        }else #gradient == NULL
        {
          if(opt.meth == "Nelder-Mead")
            opt.fun <- "constrOptim"
          else if(opt.meth %in% c("L-BFGS-B", "Brent"))
            opt.fun <- "optim"
          else
          {
            txt1 <- paste("The method", opt.meth, "cannot be used by constrOptim() nor optim() without gradient and bounds.")
            txt2 <- "Only optimization methods L-BFGS-B, Brent and Nelder-Mead can be used in such case."
            stop(paste(txt1, txt2))
          }
        }
        if(opt.fun == "constrOptim")
        {
          #recycle parameters
          npar <- length(vstart) #as in optim() line 34
          lower <- as.double(rep_len(lower, npar)) #as in optim() line 64
          upper <- as.double(rep_len(upper, npar))

          # constraints are : Mat %*% theta >= Bnd, i.e. 
          # +1 * theta[i] >= lower[i]; 
          # -1 * theta[i] >= -upper[i]

          #select rows from the identity matrix
          haslow <- is.finite(lower)
          Mat <- diag(npar)[haslow, ]
          #select rows from the opposite of the identity matrix
          hasupp <- is.finite(upper)
          Mat <- rbind(Mat, -diag(npar)[hasupp, ])
          colnames(Mat) <- names(vstart)
          rownames(Mat) <- paste0("constr", 1:NROW(Mat))

          #select the bounds
          Bnd <- c(lower[is.finite(lower)], -upper[is.finite(upper)])
          names(Bnd) <- paste0("constr", 1:length(Bnd))

          initconstr <- Mat %*% vstart - Bnd
          if(any(initconstr < 0))
            stop("Starting values must be in the feasible region.")

          opttryerror <- try(opt <- constrOptim(theta=vstart, f=fnobj, ui=Mat, ci=Bnd, grad=gradient,
                                                fix.arg=fix.arg, obs=data, mdistnam=mdistname, memp=memp, 
                                                hessian=!is.null(gradient), method=opt.meth, weights=weights, 
                                                ...), silent=TRUE)
          if(!inherits(opttryerror, "try-error"))
            if(length(opt$counts) == 1) #appears when the initial point is a solution
              opt$counts <- c(opt$counts, NA)

        }else #opt.fun == "optim"
        {
          opttryerror <- try(opt <- optim(par=vstart, fn=fnobj, fix.arg=fix.arg, obs=data, gr=gradient,
                                          mdistnam=mdistname, memp=memp, hessian=TRUE, method=opt.meth, 
                                          lower=lower, upper=upper, weights=weights, ...), silent=TRUE)       
        }

      }else #hasbound == FALSE
      {
        opt.fun <- "optim"
        opttryerror <- try(opt <- optim(par=vstart, fn=fnobj, fix.arg=fix.arg, obs=data, gr=gradient,
                                        mdistnam=mdistname, memp=memp, hessian=TRUE, method=opt.meth, lower=lower, 
                                        upper=upper, ...), silent=TRUE)       
      }
      options(warn=owarn)

      if (inherits(opttryerror,"try-error"))
      {
        warnings("The function optim encountered an error and stopped.")
        if(getOption("show.error.messages")) print(attr(opttryerror, "condition"))              
        return(list(estimate = rep(NA,length(vstart)), convergence = 100, value = NA, 
                    hessian = NA))
      }

      if (opt$convergence>0) {
        warnings("The function optim failed to converge, with the error code ",
                 opt$convergence)
      }
      if(is.null(names(opt$par)))
        names(opt$par) <- names(vstart)
      res <- list(estimate = opt$par, convergence = opt$convergence, value = opt$value, 
                  hessian = opt$hessian, optim.function=opt.fun, order=order, 
                  memp=memp, counts=opt$counts, optim.message=opt$message)  

    }else # Try to minimize the stat distance using a user-supplied optim function 
    {
      opt.meth <- NULL
      if (!cens)
      {
        options(warn=ifelse(silent, -1, 0))
        opttryerror <- try(opt <- custom.optim(fn=fnobj, fix.arg=fix.arg, obs=data, mdistnam=mdistname, 
                                               memp=memp, par=vstart, weights=weights, ...), silent=TRUE)
        options(warn=owarn)
      }else
        stop("Moment matching estimation for censored data is not yet available.")

      if (inherits(opttryerror,"try-error"))
      {
        warnings("The customized optimization function encountered an error and stopped.")
        if(getOption("show.error.messages")) print(attr(opttryerror, "condition"))              
        return(list(estimate = rep(NA,length(vstart)), convergence = 100, value = NA, 
                    hessian = NA))
      }

      if (opt$convergence>0) {
        warnings("The customized optimization function failed to converge, with the error code ",
                 opt$convergence)
      }

      res <- list(estimate = opt$par, convergence = opt$convergence, value = opt$value, 
                  hessian = opt$hessian, optim.function=custom.optim, order=order, 
                  memp=memp, counts=opt$counts, optim.message=opt$message)  

    }   

  }

  if(is.null(weights))
  {  
    loglik <- function(par, fix.arg, obs, ddistnam) 
      sum(log(do.call(ddistnam, c(list(obs), as.list(par), as.list(fix.arg)) ) ) )
  }else
  {
    loglik <- function(par, fix.arg, obs, ddistnam) 
      sum(weights * log(do.call(ddistnam, c(list(obs), as.list(par), as.list(fix.arg)) ) ) )
  }
  if(exists(ddistname))
    loglik <- loglik(res$estimate, fix.arg, data, ddistname)
  else
    loglik <- NULL

  res <- c(res, fix.arg=fix.arg, loglik=loglik, method=meth, optim.method=opt.meth, 
           fix.arg.fun=fix.arg.fun, list(weights = weights))

  return(res)
}

## old function with previous name 
momdist<-function (data, distr) 
{
  stop("the name \"momdist\" for matching moments function is NO MORE used and is replaced by \"mmedist\".")
}
```